# Is there a reliable way of detecting whether io.js or node.js is running?

Tags: node.js, io.js

The only way I can kind-of infer whether node.js or io.js is running is to check `process.versions.node`.  In io.js, I get 1.0.4.

I'm sure there's a better way - anyone know?

Comment: I've just found this question but a few days ago I asked something similar but [detecting between nodejs, iojs, jxcore, and the Microsoft fork of node with the ChakraCore js engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037072).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now the most reliable solution is to exec `node -h` and see if it contains `iojs.org` substring. If it does - it's `iojs`:

```
function isIojs(callback) {
    require('child_process').exec(process.execPath + ' -h', function(err, help) {
        return err ? callback(err) : callback(null, /iojs\.org/.test(help));
    });
}
```

The big minus of such approach - it's asynchronous. So I wrote a small library which is simplifying the job: [is-iojs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-iojs).

But frankly speaking: who knows when node version 1 will be released, maybe never. So I think for now determination based only on `process.version` is enough:

```
var isIojs = parseInt(process.version.match(/^v(\d+)\./)[1]) >= 1;
```

Also you can check `process.execPath` string, but this approach does not works for windows as far as I know.

Comment: The first solution would fail if `node` wasn't pointing to the current executable(ie two iojs and node being installed side by side...)

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat For now `node` and `iojs` cannot be installed "side by side". Also problem you described can be fixed using `process.execPath`. So I updated the answer. Thanks for remark.

Comment: They can be as long as they are installed in different places, but yeah, process.execPath is solution for it. :D