# How can my node.js code see if it's running under official nodejs, iojs, jxcore, or node-chakracore?

Tags: node.js, jxcore, chakra, iojs, chakracore

There are now several forks of nodejs for various reasons.

For my node code to see which fork it is running under, what is currently the best way?

The forks I am aware of are:

- The official nodejs release
- iojs - I guess it's now deprecated since it's rejoined the official nodejs, but it's still of interest
- JXcore - a fork that supports multiple CPUs/core; multiple JS engines including V8, Mozilla's SpiderMonkey, and Microsoft's ChakraCore; and packaging of js apps so npm doesn't need to be used by users of the apps
- Microsoft's fork of nodejs using their Edge browser's ChakraCore JS engine via a V8-compatibility shim

([I've also asked a companion question about detecting which JS engine is being used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037194) This question is only about detecting which fork is being used.)

Comment: This question has been downvoted but [a previous question asking only about nodejs vs iojs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259154) that I just found has seven upvotes. Is it just my wording?

Answer (score 4):

NodeJS and iojs can be probably checked by [process.release](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_release) :

> name: a string with a value that will always be 'node' for Node.js. For legacy io.js releases, this will be 'io.js'.

As for JXcore you can use either `process.jxversion` or `typeof jxcore !== 'undefined'`

Comment: Yes I couldn't get io.js to install since I have a node.js from after the projects re-merged. In JXcore, `process.release` is a function that can't be called. The MS port of NodeJS also has 'node' at `process.release.name` but has several other differences.

Comment: Yes, `process.release` in JXcore is currently something else than in NodeJS as it was added to JXcore before NodeJS had it (so that brings a name convergence https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/issues/790)