# How to detect from nodejs which JavaScript engine it is running on?

Tags: node.js, spidermonkey, javascript-engine, jxcore, chakra

There are now several forks of nodejs and some of them support JavaScript engines other than Google's V8 engine.

For my node code to see which JS engine it is running under, what is currently the best way?

The engines I am aware of are:

- Google's **V8** - The only engine supported by the official **node.js** and the **iojs** fork. One of the engines supported by **JXcore**.
- Mozilla's **SpiderMonkey** - One of the engines supported by **JXcore**.
- Microsoft's **ChakraCore** - The engine supported by **Microsoft**'s port of node.js and apparently one of the engines supported by **JXcore** though I haven't got that one to work yet.

([I've asked a separate question about detecting which fork of nodejs is being used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037072) This question is only about detecting the JS engine.)

Answer (score 8):

The `process` object contains a lot of information about the currently running process (in this case, node).

My `process.versions` for example, contains the current version of V8:

```
process: {
    versions: {
        http_parser: '2.5.0',
        node: '4.2.4',
        v8: '4.5.103.35',
        uv: '1.7.5',
        zlib: '1.2.8',
        ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
        icu: '56.1',
        modules: '46',
        openssl: '1.0.2e'
    }
}
```

You should be able to query this object and determine the current engine.

Comment: The fields in the `process` and `versions` objects actually have fields different between nodejs ports. I want to document the differences in an answer but so far I can't compare MS's nodejs with ChakraCore against JXcore with Chakra as I can't find out [how to use the latter on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055401).

Comment: JXcore also keeps engine version numbers in `process.versions`. Currently this is either `v8`, `sm` (SpiderMonkey) or `ch` (Chakra) .